# Element from loop is not visible in LinkButton

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I'm trying to get id from car and then set it as id in LinkButton, but car object is not visible in LinkButton and the same method which I used in element above is not working in LinkButton.

Code:

```
                <% foreach (var car in GetCars())
                    { %>
                <li>
                    <img src='<%=car.PhotoUrl %>' alt='Car photo' />
                    <asp:LinkButton id='<%=car.Id%>' runat="server" class='customButton chooseCarButton' title="Choose" OnClick="ChooseCar">Choose</asp:LinkButton>
                </li>
                <% } %>
```

Errors:

```
Parser Error
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: '<%=car.Id%>' is not a valid identifier.
```

```
IDE1007 The name 'car' does not exist in the current context.
```

Comment: Don't give the LinkButton an id of your own. Let aspnet handle that.

Comment: @VDWWD ok, but it's not a problem  I tried also in other properties and always the same error

Comment: Then you would need to bind like this: `Text='<%# car.Name %>'`

Comment: Same error:  CS0103 The name 'car' does not exist in the current context